# How can I set a Microsoft SQL field as identity but to START with a certain number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

How can I set a Microsoft SQL field as identity but to START with a certain number?

Comment: SQL. What SQL? SQL Server? Oracle? MySql?

Comment: Microsoft SQL. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), the value from which you want to start your identity is called seed.

If you want to do it from the GUI, then you can select that column and in its properties, in the identity specification section look of the IsIdentity and set it to true, then look for Identity Seed and specify the value which ever you want, you can also specify the increment as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution. "id int IDENTITY(1,1)". :D

Answer (score 28):

In SQL Server, when you declare the column as an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column, you specify a seed and increment.

The seed value is the number to start from, the increment is the amount to increment for the next number.

In this example, you start with 100, incrementing by 1:

```
column INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (100, 1)
```

If you want to change it for an existing table (so new records start from a different range), use [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx).

In this example, the table `dbo.myTable` will start with a new seed of 300:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.myTable", RESEED, 300);
```

Answer (score 5):

For an existing table, use:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0);
```

You would just substitute your starting number for the 0.

For a new table use:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].YourTableName(
[UID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       ...
 )
```

Where the 1,1 is the starting number and the increment.

Answer (score 3):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 34)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SET_IDENTITY_INSERT_ON to insert the number you want to start with, then turn it back off.