# Integer values allocation

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that generates integer values (currently on `10,230`) and I have this list of accounts which I want to assign these integer values to but will not be used in prod yet.

I want to allocate 20 of the next values, (e.g. `10,231`, `10,232`, etc.) but what I want is for the next person that will make an insert into the prod table to not take those values which I allocate for those accounts. How can I prevent those values from being assigned to someone else?

Basically, I want people to start generating values from `10,251` onward as `10,230` - `10,250` are allocated by me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a Microsoft SQL field as identity but to START with a certain number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555154/how-can-i-set-a-microsoft-sql-field-as-identity-but-to-start-with-a-certain-numb)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - it's not, as I can't use reseed for the table, what are the other options please?

Comment: Silly question:  why can't you?  Is it not an identity field?

Comment: No, we're using a rowid to generate the other integer column, the one with the (10,230) values.

Comment: If you are using rowid to generate those values then include that in the question.

Comment: Try to store rowid in a variable then check for the existence of that value in the table. If exits then again regenerate rowid else insert it